# RegEx modification for values between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I am using a RegEx at work which returns the value between parenthesis.

Eg : `Some text (123)` -> `123`

using the following RegEx : `/(?<=\().*(?=\))/`
But I have an entry which looks like this, and therefore returns this :

`Some (text) (123)` -> `text ) (123`

The value I try to catch is always at the end of the string, in the last parenthesis. Can anyone explain me what to change in my RegEx to get this value ?

Comment: How about: `/\(\d+)\)$/`

Comment: Unsure if you want to capture the 1st "123" in this example, or the second?

Comment: @beiller: "The value I try to catch is always at the end of the string"

Comment: In both examples the value I need to capture is "123", but it doesn't work with the second exemple using my regex.

Comment: @fliespl The 2nd part of that sentence "In the last parenthesis" means what?

Comment: (123), (456), (678) - last parenthesis meant he wanted to get 678.

Comment: @mario I didn't find this post, but yes it seems OP's problem is my solution :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value is always at the end, just anchor the expression and simplify it:

```
/\((\d+)\)$/
```

To match any character inside you can use a negative character set:

```
/\(([^)]+)\)$/
```

The `[^)]+` matches anything that's not a closing parentheses.

Comment: It works like a charm, many thanks ! You're too fast I can only set my question as solved in 10 minutes =)